# How to insert row that contains autoincrement column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
id, user_name, symbol, company.
```

The `id` column is the primary key and it has `autoIncrement` property.

I want to add a record to the table, I use:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO users_stocks VALUES(" + 
                                    "@user_name, @stock_symbol, @company)", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", user_name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_symbol", stock_symbol);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company);

    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    //rows number of record got inserted
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
            //Log exception
            connection.Close();
}
```

But it gives me exception (I have 4 columns and I only specify 3 here).

How can I add a row with the autoIncrement column to?

Comment: What is the exception message? Including any internal exception messages, please.

Comment: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the column names in the query.

Not specifying them means the query will try to insert to all columns, which is why it fails.

```
INSERT INTO users_stocks
(UserName, StockSymbol, Company)
VALUES
(@user_name, @stock_symbol, @company)
```

Comment: it gives me this exception: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'number', table 'C:\USERS\MICHAEL\DESKTOP\STOCKTRACKER\APP_DATA\DATABASE1.MDF.dbo.users_stocks'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: It have a problem with the fact i am not telling him what to put in the first column which is the auto increment column 'number'

Comment: @MichaelA - You need to take another look at your table definition. Are you certain it is defined as an auto increment?

Answer (score 2):

Change your SqlCommand to specify the columns explicitly.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO users_stocks ( user_name, symbol, company ) VALUES(" + "@user_name, @stock_symbol, @company)", connection);
```